# Problem solving the PDE $x u_x+y u_y=-u$ with initial conditions by characteristics methods

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm studying PDE's and found this question:

> Solve this equation and found a large area that the solution is well defined:
>
> \begin{equation}xu_x+yu_y=-u , \ u(0,y)= h(y)\end{equation}

I used the Characteristics Method described [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19nqqD12vkJbzJVEDpUpNa34omnUoGFOb).

We parametrize a curve $\Gamma(x(s,r),y(s,r))$ that passes through the point $(0,y)$ as:

\begin{array}$x(0,r)=0&\\
 y(0,r)=r&\\
\Gamma(0,y)=\Gamma(0,r)=h(r)\end{array}

Now we solve this system of ODE's: \begin{array}$\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}(s,r)=x \implies x(s,r)=c_1(r)e^s&\\
\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}(s,r)=y \implies y(s,r)=c_2(r)e^s&\\
\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}(s,r)= -z\implies z(s,r)=c_3(r)e^{-s}\end{array}

And find $c_1,c_2 \text{ and } c_3$ by the conditions of $\Gamma$.

The problem comes here because we found that \begin{array}$c_1=0 \implies x(s,r)=0&\\
c_2=r \implies y(s,r)=re^s&\\
c_3=h(r) \implies z(s,r)=h(r)e^{-s}\end{array}

Isolating $e^s$ in $y(s,r)$ we obtain that $e^s=\frac{y(s,r)}{r}$ and then $z(s,r)$ becomes:
\begin{equation}z(s,r)=\frac{rh(r)}{y(s,r)} \end{equation}

Because $x(s,r)=0$ we can't find $s$ in the variables $x$ and $y$ and that is my problem.

Thinking geometricaly while $s$ goes near to $0$, $y(s,r)$ decreases while $z(s,r)$ increases very fast at a arbitrary point $(x_0,y_0)$.
Using the conditions from the exercise the solution lies in the line $(0,y_0)$ for $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and that is weird to me.

Can someone help with this?

Comment: If you look at the first condition, you'll see it talks about whether the initial data is _non-characteristic_. If the data is non-characteristic, you can invert $r,s$ for $x,y$. Is your initial data $(0,r,)$ is non-characteristic?